# CallStateDisconnected only detected for incoming calls, not for calls made from my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-telephony

I can't detect end of call (state CallStateDisconnected), if I make call from my app. But if I receive call when my app is active, I can detect that state. I also receive state CTCallStateDialing twice or 3 times when call starts from my app. 
It used to be working under iOS5, this problems occured with iOS6.

My app del code;

```
 self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
self.callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall* call) {

    // anounce that we've had a state change in our call center
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:call.callState forKey:@"callState"]; //BREAKPOINT HERE

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CTCallStateDidChange" object:self userInfo:dict]; 

};
```

Strange thing is that it all works, if I put breakpoint in callEventHandler block and resume execution  after call finishes, then I get CallStateDisconnected correctly.

Then I subscribe to notifications in my view controller and execute this code when I receive them:

```
- (void)ctCallStateDidChange1:(NSNotification *)notification
 {
  NSString *call = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"callState"];


if ([call isEqualToString:CTCallStateDisconnected])
{
    NSLog(@"Call has been disconnected");

}
else if([call isEqualToString:CTCallStateDialing])
{

    NSLog(@"Call start");
}
else if ([call isEqualToString:CTCallStateConnected])
{
    NSLog(@"Call has just been connected");
}
else if([call isEqualToString:CTCallStateIncoming])
{
    NSLog(@"Call is incoming");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"None");
}
```

}

I make call from my app like this:

```
        UIWebView *callWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
        [self.view addSubview:callWebview];
        NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:number];
        [callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];
```

I also logged app state and I get `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`

after I start call, then I go to `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`

and after call is finished back to `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application.`

Is that strange, that `DidBecomeActive` is called after call is made and before going to background?

Comment: It still does work on iOS 5, I just tried it and saw both "call start" and "call has been disconnected". The appDelegate state transitions were all sensible too. Can't try it on iOS 6 until tomorrow.

Comment: I would be very helpfulm if you could try it on iOS6 tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: When you run it without a break point what is logged compared to with a break point? I know if you wait until after the call is done to resume you're app only receives a single update (in this case that the call disconnected) otherwise you get them all. Are you just repeatedly getting "Call start", nothing or what without a breakpoint? Are you notified of everything except the disconnect state?

Comment: Only "call start" is logged without breakpoint, and "call start" and "Call has been disconnected" with call stopped during paused execution (breakpoint).

Answer (score 6):

Here's the log from an iOS 5 phone:

```
2012-12-02 22:00:00.252 TestPhone[2297:707] didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
2012-12-02 22:00:00.352 TestPhone[2297:707] applicationDidBecomeActive:
2012-12-02 22:00:06.708 TestPhone[2297:707] applicationWillResignActive:
2012-12-02 22:00:10.582 TestPhone[2297:1c03] Call start
2012-12-02 22:00:11.016 TestPhone[2297:707] applicationDidBecomeActive:
2012-12-02 22:00:12.536 TestPhone[2297:707] applicationWillResignActive:
2012-12-02 22:00:12.564 TestPhone[2297:707] applicationDidEnterBackground:
2012-12-02 22:00:36.543 TestPhone[2297:707] applicationWillEnterForeground:
2012-12-02 22:00:36.769 TestPhone[2297:707] applicationDidBecomeActive:
2012-12-02 22:00:36.840 TestPhone[2297:2e07] Call has been disconnected
2012-12-02 22:00:36.854 TestPhone[2297:707] applicationWillResignActive:
2012-12-02 22:00:49.885 TestPhone[2297:707] applicationDidBecomeActive:
```

and here's the log from an iOS 6 phone:

```
2012-12-03 06:27:55.401 TestPhone[7734:907] didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
2012-12-03 06:27:55.462 TestPhone[7734:907] applicationDidBecomeActive:
2012-12-03 06:28:01.396 TestPhone[7734:907] applicationWillResignActive:
2012-12-03 06:28:04.345 TestPhone[7734:907] applicationDidBecomeActive:
2012-12-03 06:28:04.401 TestPhone[7734:1803] Call start
2012-12-03 06:28:05.824 TestPhone[7734:907] applicationWillResignActive:
2012-12-03 06:28:05.826 TestPhone[7734:907] applicationDidEnterBackground:
2012-12-03 06:28:17.318 TestPhone[7734:907] applicationWillEnterForeground:
2012-12-03 06:28:17.329 TestPhone[7734:907] applicationDidBecomeActive:
```

The "disconnected" message has just disappeared. (This isn't an answer, it's an observation.)

Here's the code I used. I I created a single-view application in xcode with a single button in the xib, and this is the whole of my UIViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
    self.callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall* myCall) {
        NSString *call = myCall.callState;
        if ([call isEqualToString:CTCallStateDisconnected])
            NSLog(@"Call has been disconnected");
        else if([call isEqualToString:CTCallStateDialing]) 
            NSLog(@"Call start");
        else if ([call isEqualToString:CTCallStateConnected])
            NSLog(@"Call has just been connected");
        else if([call isEqualToString:CTCallStateIncoming])
            NSLog(@"Call is incoming");
        else
            NSLog(@"None");
    };
}

- (IBAction)callButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *number = @"tel:01234567890";
    UIWebView *callWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    callWebview.frame = self.view.frame;    
    [self.view addSubview:callWebview];
    NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:number];
    [callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];
}
@end
```

Comment: and the message at 22:00:36.854 was caused when the phone popped up a "Your remaining credit is..." window.

Comment: Thank you for you observation. My ios6 phone behaves the same. Is this  iOS6 bug and should it be reported to Apple?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't seem to be right. I added my variant of your code to my answer. Feel free to send that to Apple if it helps.

Comment: @DixieFlatline , did you get any response?

Comment: Yes, yesterday i got this: This is a follow up to Bug ID# 12796040. This bug has been closed as a Duplicate. The issue is being tracked under the original Bug ID# 12522984 which is also listed in the Related Problem section of your bug report. To check the status of the original bug report, please visit the Related Problem section of the Problem Detail view of your closed duplicate bug.