# How can I get the callback after called a phone number from an IOS application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

According to Apple's documentation, in order to make phone call from my app, I need to implement like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://11223344"]];
```

when I completed my call, my app return to foreground by this method:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Here is my question:

The invoker applicationWillEnterForeground: has no symbol which tells me that the call is ended. **So how can I know applicationWillEnterForeground: is invoked after a phone call?**

Comment: I might be wrong but if a phone conversation has ended, then the app will be relaunched such as when you are playing a game. When an app gets relaunched it will call one of its delegate methods in the AppDelegate. This means when it reaches that delegate method, then obviously, your phone call will likely have ended (assuming a phone conversation where the user does not minimize the phone call and reopen their app).

Comment: There is more about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553635/callstatedisconnected-only-detected-for-incoming-calls-not-for-calls-made-from/13678256#13678256 but iOS 6 seems to have a bug here.