# CTCallState event handler not getting called if no breakpoint is set

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am experiencing the weirdest bug ever, I am running the app on my iPhone, and I have the following code:

```
self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
    [self.callCenter setCallEventHandler: ^(CTCall* call) {
        if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDisconnected]) {
            NSLog(@"call ended");
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                NSLog(@"on main thread!");
                NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                [userInfo setValue:weakSelf.recordRef forKey:kContactKey];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kCallEndedNotification object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
            });
        }
    }];
```

For some reason, this block of code is not called. But if I put a breakpoint on the if statement, then it gets called. Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

It's, I believe, an iOS SKD 6 bug. Because event "CTCallStateDisconnected" should be called in the moment, when your app is in background, so it's not called at all. The reason, why it's ok when you put breakepoint there, is, I think, because of time when the event is called. If it's stopped at breakepoint, call is still going and event is called when your app is in foreground.

Look here, in iOS5 this was working:
[setCallEventHandler test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553635/callstatedisconnected-only-detected-for-incoming-calls-not-for-calls-made-from/13678256#13678256)