# How to determine if an app is returning from a phone call or resuming from background?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I make phone call from my application using:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://XXXXXXXXXX"]];`

When the user ends the call, the default Apple-provided Phone app goes to the background and my application resumes focus. This happens automatically.

Now here's what I want: **I'd like to call a method every time (and only when) the user returns from a call.**

I tried calling this method from `applicationWillEnterForeground:` or `applicationDidBecomeActive:` but these callbacks are fired at other times when the application is being launched from the background state(which I dont want).

I'd like to determine if my application is being launched from the background state or if it is returning from a phone call so I can perform a certain task only in the former case and not latter.  Any ideas?

----EDIT----

Here's how I finally did it:

See: [CallStateDisconnected only detected for incoming calls, not for calls made from my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553635/callstatedisconnected-only-detected-for-incoming-calls-not-for-calls-made-from?lq=1)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [self listenForCalls];
}

- (void)listenForCalls {

    self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
    self.callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall* myCall) {
        NSString *call = myCall.callState;
        if([call isEqualToString:CTCallStateDialing]) {
              //do ur stuff
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can use telephony framework, Which provides you call states to determine the state of phone.
You can find out detail from here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009590

Comment: Yup. Using the callState property of CTCall to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Why not save a flag indicating that your app sent the user to the phone call. When your applications becomes active, if the flag is set, do the return from phone call method.

ex.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"DidStartPhoneCall"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://XXXXXXXXXX"]];
```

Then something like,

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive {
    BOOL activeFromCall = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:"DidStartPhoneCall"]
    if(activeFromCall && [activeFromCall boolValue] == YES) {
     // do your method 
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"DidStartPhoneCall"]; // reste flag
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have been doing. But there's a problem with this approach. Every time one calls the openURL: method to make the call, the user is prompted an alert view where he can 'Call' or 'Cancel'. What if the user cancels?  In that case setting the "DidStartPhoneCall" flag to YES before launching the openURL: method   is incorrect right? So this doesn't work in this scenario.

Comment: Maybe only set the flag when the `openUrl` method returns `YES`?

Comment: returns YES on 'Cancel' as well as 'Call' :(

Comment: Hmm, tricky! If they press 'Call' does your app get a `applicationWillEnterBackground` notifcation (or similar)? Then this could be accomplished with 2 flags.

Comment: yep... and what if the user won't come back, just kills the application and next time when the application starts, you will determine it is coming back like it would be after a phone call.